# Reversing a string hash function

Tags: c#, hash, reverse

I have the following function that *hashes* a `string`:

```
public static uint hashString(string myString)
{
     uint hash = 0;

     foreach (char c in myString)
     {
         hash *= 0x1F;
         hash += c;
     }

     return hash;
}
```

So if I want to hash `hello` it will produce `99162322`.

Is it possible to write a **reverse** function that takes in a `number` and spits out the `string` (given that the `string` *result* is *unknown*)?

Comment: No. hash != encryption - it is more like a checksum

Comment: The most you can do with a hash is to get some input that when hashed will produce the same hash as what you originally had. There is no guarantee that you will get back the original string. Depending on the complexity of the hash algorithm the job of obtaining input that produces a given hash may or may not be difficult or a long-running process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you don't use *cryptographic* hash, your implementation is easy to *reverse* (i.e. return **some** `string` which has the given hash value)

**Code:**

```
public static uint hashString(string myString) {
  //DONE: validate public methods' parameters
  if (null == myString)
    return 0;

  uint hash = 0;

  //DONE: hash function must never throw exceptions
  unchecked {
    foreach (char c in myString) {
      hash *= 0x1F;
      hash += c;
    }
  }

  return hash;
}

private static string HashReverse(uint value) {
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

  for (; value > 0; value /= 31) 
    sb.Append((char)(value % 31));

  return string.Concat(sb.ToString().Reverse());
}
```

**Demo:** (given a `hash` we produce a `string` and compute `hash` from it to check)

```
uint[] tests = new uint[] {
  99162322,
  123,
  456
};

// Since the string can contain control characters, let's provide its Dump
string Dump(string value) => string.Join(" ", value.Select(c =>((int) c).ToString("x4")));

string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, tests
  .Select(test => new { 
    test,
    reversed = HashReverse(test)
  })
  .Select(item => $"{item.test,9} :: {Dump(item.reversed),-30} :: {hashString(item.reversed),9}"));

Console.WriteLine(report);
```

**Outcome:**

```
 99162322 :: 0003 000e 000b 0012 0012 0012  ::  99162322
      123 :: 0003 001e                      ::       123
      456 :: 000e 0016                      ::       456
```

Please, note, that *many* a `string` produce the *same* hash value (say, `"hello"` and mine `"\u0003\u000e\u000b\u0012\u0012\u0012"`)

Answer (score 2):

No.

One of the fundamental points of hashing is that it's irreversible.

There are many string that will produce the has 99162322, so while it might be possible to find all of them (given a maximum string length), but there would be no way to determine which one was 'correct'.

Comment: I'm sorry, but since `hashString` is **not** a **crypto**hash it's *easy* to reverse

Comment: Only if there's a limit on the string length.

Comment: It depends on your definition of "reverse". OP wants the original string, getting *a* string is feasible, getting the original one is not.